# XMPP MUC how to list rooms that user is affiliated with

Tags: list, xmpp, affiliate

Im making a whatsapp like client as far as chatting goes. I need to populate a "feeds" area with all the rooms that the user is affiliated with. I cant find anywere how to do this.

This works to get ALL rooms:

```
     <iq from='hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda'
     to='conference.someplace.com'
     type='get'>
     <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'/>
     </iq>
```

I need to get just the rooms the user is afiliated with.

Thanks.